# good example applications combining rails 3 and sproutcore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sproutcore

I am trying to write a sproutcore frontend for a rails 3.1 application I am making. I have had a look at the sproutcore guides, but I am interested in seeing real examples how to use sproutcore together with rails 3(.1).

I have found two examples, but each is totally different:

1. A [todo-app](https://github.com/drnic/todos-bulk-api-demo) created using [bulk_api](https://github.com/drogus/bulk_api): an interesting approach using a specific REST-style to minimise the traffic. But it proposes to place the sproutcore app in `app/sproutcore`, and is still a bit unclear to me how that actually hooks in completely.
2. [Travis-ci](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci) which seems to be a very clean example, rails 3.1, to use sproutcore. It is not yet completely clear to me, but all sproutcore js is cleanly stored inside `app/assets/javascript/apps` and as far as i can tell, the `application.html` just loads the js and provides the frame where everything is loaded into.

Do you know any other examples? How do you use sproutcore in your rails app?

Comment: you should specify sproutcore 1.x vs sproutcore 2

Comment: Good point: Sproutcore 2, which was obvious to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you describe is the same way that you integrate backbone.js into a rails app, and it seems to work very well

https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails

This stores backbone in

app/assets/javascripts/backbone/
app/assets/javascripts/backbone/app/models
app/assets/javascripts/backbone/app/controllers

And then there is a script tag in the view that just initializes backbone

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Blog is the app name
    window.router = new Blog.Routers.PostsRouter({posts: <%= @posts.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

I imagine a similar process for sproutcore would make sense

Comment: Yes, thank you. In travis-ci they drop the backbone folder and just create an `app` folder. In spine.js they follow the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a demo-project: [sproutcore-on-rails](https://github.com/thecatwasnot/sproutcore-on-rails) that did manage to make things clearer for me.