# how to deploy a sproutcore app with rails backend using capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, sproutcore

My project code structure is as follows:

```
myapp/
  rails_code/
    app/ models/ views/ assets/ etc 
  sproutcore_code/
    sp/
      apps/ Buildfile etc
```

I deploy with capistrano, and I have the rails app set up with nginx and passenger on the server, so that the server's root directory is /path/to/myapp/rails_code/public, and it works. But the rails code is the backend. I need to set up the sproutcore code as well.

So how should i set up nginx for sproutcore code in the myapp/sproutcore_code/sp directory, and how should i change the cap deploy script to build the sproutcore app?

Answer (score 1):

I think what is most done that you actually move the sproutcore js to your `app/assets/javascripts` folder.

You should have some home-page, served by your rails-application that contains and starts the sproutcore application.

If you do it that way, you do not have to change anything to your deployment process.

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549114/good-example-applications-combining-rails-3-and-sproutcore) recently asking for demo-applications with sproutcore, and found [Travis-CI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci) to be very informational for me. Not sure how you combine that with the actual sproutcore application development though.

[EDIT]: I found a good demo-project making things clearer: [sproutcore-on-rails](https://github.com/thecatwasnot/sproutcore-on-rails). Hope it helps you.

Since then I have looking more to [spine.js](http://spinejs.com/), which has a direct integration with rails, and found that much easier to start with. They provide generators that builds a folder structure inside your `app/assets/javascripts`, and helps quick scaffolding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how does the home-page start the sproutcore application? i put up a page, example welcome#index which when opened, should start the sproutcore application? sorry i am a newbie on sproutcore!!

Comment: I should not know myself, it was a hurdle I could not take myself either. I did just stumble accross a demo-project that seems to make things clearer. Hope it helps you too.